# Output file much larger than input files after cat + grep

Tags: grep, glob, cat

I have 18 csv files, all between 1mb and 14mb. The sum of all files is 64mb. I want to create a new csv file that contains a subset of those files-- only the lines featuring the pattern "Hello" (or "HELLO", or "hello" ...). Here's what I'm doing

```
   cat *.csv | head -n 1 > new.csv   # I want to create a header first
   cat *.csv | grep -i "hello" >> new.csv
```

I'm running Debian on `WSL`. The output file is much, much larger than the original 64mb (I stopped the process after 1+ hour, and the file was 300+ GB).

How can a subset of a text file be larger than the original files? Does it have anything to do with `WSL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an OS issue.  When you redirect your output to `new.csv`, shell creates that file first, before the glob expression `*.csv` is evaluated.  That means the expansion of `*.csv` would include `new.csv` as well.  That seems like the root cause of the recursive grep issue you are facing.

You are reading all the files twice, which is not necessary.  You can make your operation a lot simpler and efficient with a single `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print} tolower($0) ~ /hello/ {print}' *.csv > csv.new
mv csv.new new.csv
```

- since the output file is named `csv.new` it won't interfere with the glob `*.csv`
- `NR==1` picks up the first line (header) from the very first file

The awk command can be written more succinctly as:

```
awk 'NR==1 || tolower($0) ~ /hello/' *.csv > csv.new
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `*.csv` and redirecting the output to `new.csv` which falls under `*.csv` which is causing recursion in grep result. perhaps you can try,

```
grep -i hello *.csv --exclude="new.csv"  >> new.csv
```